# amsart package printing author names twice on title page, how to fix this?

Tags: amsart, author

I am trying to make a document using the 'amsart' class that has both full author names and short author names. If I only have full author names, the title page will have the title, then have the authors. For some reason though if I also include short author names, the title page will start with a header involving the author names, then list the title, then reprints the authors names again. How do I get rid of the header listing the author's names on the title page while still using short author names?

Example code:

```
\documentclass[]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\title{Titley title}
\author{Authory author}{Author}
\author{Authory author}{Author}

\maketitle

hi

\end{document}`
```

Comment: `\author` command takes just one mandatory argument and by using two, the second is just printed (without relation with the `\author` command)... The second argument you gave (the short version) should be placed before the full version inside `[]` because it is optional argument. So, try :`\author[Short Name]{Long Name Here}`

Comment: Yes, thank you! I also just figured this out because you are totally correct, what I was seeing and thinking was a header was just these names printed. Adding the short author names in `[]` before the main argument in `\author` fixed everything. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Happy TeXing!

Comment: @koleygr -- Even though the problem is an input error, this question hasn't been asked before, and since someone else might have the same problem in the future, you should make an answer so the question doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the command `\author` in a wrong way.

The arguments of the `(La)TeX` commands, has two types:

1. mandatory arguments: That are required from the command and usually have to be placed inside curly braces: `{}` ... (Note that some commands like \bfseries can affect everything inside their inner group after their appearance and so we don't really call the rest of the group "an argument" and that some times, a command that expect two arguments can access on them without the need of the curly braces but almost always the curly braces are recommended to be used. [try `\frac a b` and then try `\frac a bc` ... After this test you will understand why curly braces are suggested anyway.])
2. Optional arguments, that **usually (but not always)** are required before the mandatory argument(s) of the command and are placed inside square brackets (`[]`).

`\author` command takes just one mandatory argument (and one optional). So, its syntax is `\author[Short name]{Long Name}` (with the optional argument being... optional)

By using two arguments inside curly braces, the second is just printed (without relation with the `\author` command)... and just printed out as a text.